# Making a gradient-like vector field a gradient vector field via choosing a Riemannian metric.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, morse-theory

Let $\xi$ be a vector field on manifold $M^n$ which is a gradient-like vector field for a some Morse function $f$. Prove that there exists a Riemannian metric on $M$ such that $\xi$ is a gradient vector field for $M$.

Comment: Do you have a precise definition of "gradient-like" in mind, or is coming up with the right conditions part of the question?

Comment: I guess that author thinks about "gradient-like vector fields" defined as here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient-like_vector_field

Formally:

Away from critical points  $X \cdot f > 0$.

Around every critical point there is a neighborhood on which $f$ is given as in the Morse lemmas:
$$f(x) = f(b) - x_1^2 - \cdots - x_{\alpha}^2 + x_{\alpha +1}^2 + \cdots + x_n^2 $$
and on which $X$ equals the gradient of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

I have some doubts whether definitions of Lyapunov function and gradient-like dynamical system strictly coincide, specially at points where the gradient (or best, the differential of the Lyapunov function) vanishes.

But I think the question is basically answered here:
dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00605-011-0322-4